# Google Apps integration to Basecamp & Highrise

Tags: google-apps, basecamp, 37-signals, highrise

I am looking for Google Apps integration for Basecamp & Highrise. Is there anything out there that will integrate:

```
Google Contacts  <->   Highrise Contacts
Google Docs      <->   Writeboards
Google Docs      <->   Files
Google Tasks     <->   TO-DO's
Google Mail      <->   Messages
Google Calendar  <->   Calendar
```

I've seen...

- [http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=6555+11590890867758873917](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=6555%2011590890867758873917)
- [http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=5260+12920783959265872258](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=5260%2012920783959265872258)

...but nothing appears to be out there for the whole shebang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [cloudHQ](http://cloudHQ.net) service, you can manage all your work documents in a single interface and keep files synched between Basecamp, Google Docs, Dropbox and SugarSync. 
No need to download and attach files – just edit and save files directly on cloudHQ and keep your assets all in one place. 
All your Basecamp project attachments can be in Google Docs so you can share them and collaborate on them directly from a Google Docs interface.

[cloudHQ on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/user/cloudHQnet)

Comment: Highrise doesn't integrate with Google Docs, in the sense that, say, Wrike does, by letting you attach a Google Doc to a contact. And 3rd party integrations like [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/google-docs/highrise/) don't do the trick either.

Answer (score 0):

Good ol' integration. Always a pain.

Perhaps look into something that consolidates more of what you need into one system, and bypass the integration entirely. WORKetc integrates CRM, project management, collaboration tools, and billing into one system - and it integrates with Gmail among other google apps. Managing all operations through one system is much more efficient and saves a lot as well.

Answer (score 0):

Highrise doesn't integrate with Google Docs, in the sense that, say, Wrike or Insightly do, by letting you attach a Google Doc to a task, project or contact. And 3rd party integrations like [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/google-docs/highrise/) don't do the trick either.

[image]